# Why Can't I copy a folder to a disk that is larger than my folder?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, command-line, rsync, cp

I am using ubuntu 18.04-4 and want to move a large directory (yocto build directory for my project) from my `~/Desktop` to an external drive (ext4 formatted). The external drive is a 512 GB empty drive. Whenever i attempt to copy the folder to the external drive using `cp -r` or `rsync -ah`, After hours of copying, I get the following error:

```
No space left on device (28)
```

When I check the space on the drive (after the copy fails), I find that it is actually full!

`df -hT` shows the following 2 relevant lines:

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
/dev/sda1      ext4      246G  212G   23G  91% /  
/dev/sdb1      ext4      469G  445G   24K 100% /media/builder/WorkSpace
```

`du -sh` on my source folder shows that the source is 111 GB.

Before issuing the `cp` (or `rsync`) command, `df -hT` shows:

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
/dev/sdb1      ext4      469G   73M  445G   1% /media/builder/WorkSpace
```

So the destination drive is definitely empty.

The suggestion that I have run out of Inodes does not seem to apply to my case. as can be seen from the df -hT output above, my case is actually using all the space.

The destination drive is freshly formatted and is definitely large enough. Why is the copied data much larger than the source folder (and the entire source disk, for that matter)? What could be causing this?

**EDIT:** The suggestion that I have run out of Inodes does not seem to apply to my case. as can be seen from the df -hT output above, my case is actually using all the space.

The exact commands I tried using are as follows:

```
sudo cp -r Desktop/Yocto_test /media/builder/Workspace/
rsync -ah /home/builder/Desktop/Yocto_test /media/builder/WorkSpace
```

The result of the "df" command related to that (target) disk is:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on /dev/sdb1  
491173784 466153780         0 100% /media/builder/WorkSpace
```

`df -i` yields:

```
Filesystem       Inodes    IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on /dev/sdb1  
31260672 15285870 15974802   49% /media/builder/WorkSpace
```

Some other tests requested in the comments:

```
df -hi | grep -E 'Inodes|sd[ab]1'  
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on  
/dev/sda1         16M  7.4M  8.3M   48% /  
/dev/sdb1         30M   15M   16M   49% /media/builder/WorkSpace  

du -xms ~/Desktop/Yocto_test/ /media/builder/WorkSpace  
113145  /home/builder/Desktop/Yocto_test/  
455157  /media/builder/WorkSpace
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linux: no space left on device error with 50% free space](https://superuser.com/questions/310076/linux-no-space-left-on-device-error-with-50-free-space)

Comment: I have added an EDIT that explains why i think that is not the case. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Is that folder carrying many small files? What's the target file system ... exFAT?

Comment: Please check block sizes: `sudo tune2fs <deviceName> | grep 'Block size'`

Comment: @EugenRieck Yes, the folder has many small files as well as large files. The target is ext4 just like the source. You can see this in the df -hT output i shared that shows the source filesystem (/dev/sda1) and the destination filesystem (/dev/sdb1).

Comment: @gronostaj I think you are missing a -l in that command. Anyway I checked the block size for both partitions (source /dev/sda1 and destination /dev/sdb1) and they're both 4096.

Comment: I know you say you've checked the number of inodes. Here I'm interested in the number used compared to the source. `df -hi | grep -E 'Inodes|sd[ab]1'` please. Also `du -xms ~/Desktop/directory_you_are_copying /media/builder/WorkSpace` would be interesting to compare

Comment: Final question for now. Are you copying sparse files? Try `cp --sparse=always ...` or `rsync -S ...`

Comment: I've another question for you. What are the actual `cp` and `rsync` commands (including any flags and options) you're using?

Comment: @roaima I have edited the response to include the exact copy commands i tested with.

Comment: @roaima

df -hi | grep -E 'Inodes|sd[ab]1'

>Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on  
>/dev/sda1         16M  7.4M  8.3M   48% /
/dev/sdb1         30M   15M   16M   49% /media/builder/WorkSpace

The "du -xms" command is taking long to execute, I will post the result when it completes.

Comment: Please could you add your updates to the question. Put everything in one place (not spread across the comments) so that it's easy for people to read your question -make it easy for us to help you

Comment: OK. Sorry about that. I'm new here. Is there anything else i should test? I will test the -sparse=always option and update this tomorrow.

Comment: @roaima It still behaves the same even with --sparse=always. I monitored the disk usage from another terminal and when I saw that it reached 50% disk space, I aborted the copy. I can create a backup of the folder with tar -czvf . I still don't have an answer to why it can't simply copy.

Comment: @roaima I have solved the issue finally and have posted my solution as the correct answer. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally figured out why this was happening, and it was not caused by sparse files, block size issues or even running out of Inodes!

The problem was that Yocto (the build tool that created most of the files in the directory that I'm trying to copy) really loves to use hard links. and most of the millions of files it created are actually hard links to other files in the same directory. Therefore they don't consume additional space.

cp (and rsync) do not preserve hard links by default. when they encounter a hard linked file, they will create a whole new inode for it and will end up multiplying the size of an inode by the number of hard links to it!

This also explains why I could `tar czvf` the directory. Tar's default behavior is to preserve hard links.

I now can use `cp -a` to successfully copy my directory to external storage like this:

```
  sudo cp -a Yocto_test /media/builder/WorkSpace/
```

I hope this helps someone else with the same issue. Thanks everyone for your suggestions!

Comment: Good catch. `rsync -aH`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are running into a block size dilemma: The ext4 file system will use a full block even for the smallest file. This implies, that if you copy a small file (e.g. 300 bytes) from a 512B blocked device to a 4K blocked device the used space will quadruple.

Along the same lines, the space used by a directory will quadruple - so a deep folder structure will use up an appreciable amoount of space.

Things you can do: Create a big file on the new disk and assign a loop device to it, then format it with a small block size and use it to store the small files.

Comment: But The block size (4096) and filesystem type (ext4) on both my source and destination partitions are the same. I understand what you're suggesting, but wouldn't the same thing apply to the source filesystem?